# Change document Font Size in ITextSharp

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, itext, font-size

I have this little script that generate a table in a .pdf file, but the text is too big.  How do I add another font size/type for it?

```
Dim form As New HtmlForm

form.Controls.Add(gvEvents)
Dim sw As New StringWriter
Dim htmlWriter As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
Dim htmlContent As String = sw.ToString()

Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Holdkalender.pdf")
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)

form.Controls(0).RenderControl(htmlWriter)
Dim sr As New StringReader(sw.ToString())
Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50)
Dim htmlparser As New HTMLWorker(pdfDoc)
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream)
pdfDoc.Open()
htmlparser.Parse(sr)
pdfDoc.Close()
Response.Write(pdfDoc)
Response.End()
```

**EDIT:**

I have tried this, but it gives me an Ielement Error:

```
Protected Sub btnGeneratePDF_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnGeneratePDF.Click
BindEvents(Convert.ToInt32(ddlEventSize.SelectedValue))
Dim form As New HtmlForm

form.Controls.Add(gvEvents)
Dim sw As New StringWriter
Dim htmlWriter As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
Dim htmlContent As String = sw.ToString()
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Holdkalender.pdf")
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)

form.Controls(0).RenderControl(htmlWriter)
Dim sr As New StringReader(sw.ToString())
Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50) 'Paper Size and margin
Dim htmlparser As New HTMLWorker(pdfDoc)
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream)
pdfDoc.Open()
Dim ftlbl As Font = Nothing
ftlbl = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 5)
pdfDoc.Add(ftlbl)
Try
    htmlparser.Parse(sr)
Catch ex As Exception
    'Display parser errors in PDF.
    Dim paragraph As New Paragraph("FEJL!" + ex.Message)
    Dim text As Chunk = TryCast(paragraph.Chunks(0), Chunk)
    If text IsNot Nothing Then
        text.Font.Color = BaseColor.RED
    End If
    pdfDoc.Add(paragraph)
Finally
    pdfDoc.Close()
    Response.Write(pdfDoc)
    Response.End()
End Try

End Sub
```

**EDIT 2:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this to give format to your table titles

**EDIT**

```
//add a Paragraph to the document with an specify format
 Dim TableFont   = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.BOLD)

 pdfDoc.Open()  
 pdfDoc.Add(New Paragraph(sr.ReadToEnd(),TableFont)
```

Comment: hi i have tryed  Dim TableFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.BOLD)
        pdfDoc.Open()

Comment: and    Dim styles As StyleSheet = New iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet()
        pdfDoc.Open()
        styles.LoadTagStyle("body", "font-family", "tahona")
        styles.LoadTagStyle("body", "font-size", "6px")

Comment: but i still got the same big font for the pdf i got in A4 paper format.

Comment: @ThomasBøgPetersen I have update the code , now it should work

Comment: if i add this pdfDoc.Add(New Paragraph(sr, TableFont)) or this pdfDoc.Add(New Paragraph(TableFont)) then i get the image u see in mail question.

Comment: You're using HTMLWorker. That class is deprecated because it had too many errors. It has been replaced by XML Worker.

Comment: @ThomasBøgPetersen None of the overload methods of the Paragraph accepts an stringreader object as a paremeter you have to call the the ReadToEnd() method of the stringreader class, I have updated the code.

Comment: Hi thx, now i only got one issue, if i add that code, then my PDF if gen. but not just with text, all the HTML tags is showed aswell like HTML view.

Comment: @ThomasBøgPetersen Use the html decode to filter the html tags generated in your output pdf document.

Comment: ok so i do this again after the pdfDoc.Add Dim htmlWriter As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
    Dim htmlContent As String = sw.ToString()
Im new to this so sry if i dont get it.